# Caused by: java.net.ConnectException

Tags: lotus

I am trying to connect to a lotus domino server . For which i am creating session through java code by following way :

```
String ior = NotesFactory.getIOR("172.17.245.160");
Session s = NotesFactory.createSessionWithIOR(ior,"Test Mobility/MUM/TCSDEV","c@r33r");
```

I am getting ior string
but even if i am connecting to 172.17.245.160

i am getting error:

```
NotesException: Could not open Notes session
at lotus.domino.cso.Session.initSession(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.cso.Session.<init>(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.cso.Session.createSession(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSessionUP(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSessionWithIOR(Unknown Source)
at com.lotus.platform1.runNotes(platform1.java:29)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect Host: 192.168.245.160 Port: 63148 vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 1 completed: No
```

I dont know why even if i am passing my ip as 172.17.245.160 in my getIOR method

i am getting error for Host: 192.168.245.160 Port: 63148
as

```
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect Host: 192.168.245.160 Port: 63148 vmcid: 0x0 minor code: 1 completed: No
```

please help me !

Answer (score 0):

Is the diiop server task running?

Do you have any type of filewall blocking port 63148?

The initial request for getIOR goes over port 80, so that could explain why that part seems to be working.

See 'Getting the IOR' in [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Java_access_pt1/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to define the Host name/Address for DIIOP.
You can do this at Domino Administrator on my Domino Server the section Internetprtocoll/DIIOP

[image]